# file path is not working, when upload file in server in oreo?

Tags: java, android, android-8.0-oreo

```
public class FilePath {
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    // check here to KITKAT or new version
    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {

        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                        + split[1];
            }
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"),
                    Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { split[1] };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection,
                    selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

        // Return the remote address
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
 * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context
 *            The context.
 * @param uri
 *            The Uri to query.
 * @param selection
 *            (Optional) Filter used in the query.
 * @param selectionArgs
 *            (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
 * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
 */
public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri,
                                   String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = { column };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
                selection, selectionArgs, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * @param uri
 *            The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri
            .getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri
 *            The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri
            .getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri
 *            The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri
            .getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri
 *            The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
 */
public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
    return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri
            .getAuthority());
}
}
```

i have try lot of code but not working i want to upload all type file on php server.

```
00:34:31.846 25859-25859/e.admin.upload E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: e.admin.upload, PID: 25859
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/166 flg=0x1 }} to activity {e.admin.upload/e.admin.upload.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI: content://downloads/public_downloads/166
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4402)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI: content://downloads/public_downloads/166
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:165)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:418)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:802)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:752)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:710)
        at e.admin.upload.FilePath.getDataColumn(FilePath.java:105)
        at e.admin.upload.FilePath.getPath(FilePath.java:42)
        at e.admin.upload.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:133)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7454)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4353)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4402) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
2019-06-28 00:34:31.910 25859-25859/e.admin.upload I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 25859 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Not working means? Are you not able to get path ? Also `>=24` have you gone through `FileProvider`?

Comment: i don't understand, what are you saying..

Comment: What is the error you are seeing - please add the complete stacktrace to your question

Comment: when i comment file path class in main activity then app not crash

Comment: selected file path is not a file